# How to have a gallery with a changeable icon overlayed upon each image in Android?

Tags: android, layout, gallery

- I've got an array of images, which I want to display in a gallery.
- I want each image to have a small icon overlayed inside it, on the bottom right hand corner (e.g. a light bulb).
- When the user clicks on the image or the icon, the icon will change from the 'lighbulb_off' image to the 'lightbulb_on' image, and the index of the clicked image will be added to a Vector of 'clicked images'.

Is there a way to have a custom layout for each item in a gallery? If so, each gallery item could be the original image, with the icon positioned within it using a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a custom layout for each item in a Gallery?

Yes. You need to extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView()` to do what you want. Here is [a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that discusses the concept -- while it uses `ListView` as the example, the same technique should apply for Gallery.

Note that this excerpt should be updated in the next ~12 hours to be much improved, so, um, don't rush to download it right away. :-)